# camera application android flash issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-camera, android-camera2

i am facing a problem in camera apps. in  flash how can i change the button on click flash button like flash off,flash on,flash auto,when the button change functionality should be change according to the button.
 And other one is if the flash function is ON, the phone take the 1st photo with flash, the flash function still ON but on the second photo don’t enable the flash.

```
flashCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPressed) {
                flashCameraButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onflash));

                flashOnButton();
            } else if (isPressed) {
                flashCameraButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.offflash));
                isPressed = !isPressed;
                flashOffButton();
            } else
                flashCameraButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onflash));
            flashOnButton();
        }
    });


private void flashOnButton() {
    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
            param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON
                    : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            flashmode = !flashmode;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
  private void flashOffButton() {
    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
            param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF
                    : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            flashmode = !flashmode;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get these lines

```
param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON
                : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

and

```
param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF
                : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
```

Shouldnt they be on:off and off:on or so? Im not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve.